# How to migrate Shopware 6 SalesChannels settings from local to prod environment?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I would like to migrate my salesChannels settings (Payment methods, Shipping methods, etc) from a local environment to the prod environment
I used shopware-cli to pull my project settings (shopware-cli project config pull) but for salesChannels settings i only get:

```
- sales_channel: Storefront
      settings:
        storefront.themeSeed: 018df042377c700184e04a7d117a8359
- sales_channel: Storefront_2
      settings:
        storefront.themeSeed: 018df041afbe7190a735607559f2690d
```

how can i pull more saleschannel info? or how else could i get the saleschannel config?